# sql order by if field is matching

Tags: sql

I have a mysql statement that searches in 2 fields like '%%', abbreviation and fullname
I am ordering by name.
I was wondering if there is a way to say , if abbreviation matches the whole field, then show abbreviation first, otherwise, sort by name?

This is my current script

```
SELECT DISTINCT abbreviation , Name, LOCATE('$q', NAME ) AS SortString FROM airport WHERE Name LIKE '%$q%'OR abbreviation  LIKE '$q%' ORDER BY Name "
```

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
Order by case when abbreviation = 'input' then abbreviation else name end
```